# How To Remove A Senator or Representative

Tags: united-states, senate, house-of-representatives

If the people of a state feels a Senator or Representative are not doing the job they were elected to do by the that said state, do the people of said state have any recourse in removing that person before the term is up?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, To recall is not the same thing as to remove.

Comment: @agc Please explain what you think is the difference between remove and recall.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, The verb *remove* is more definite in referring to specific outcome, rather than a possible one, and more abstract in encompassing all the methods of *possible* removal, whether it be a successful or a failed recall, an impeachment, tar and feathering, *etc*.   Example:  if Gov. Foughbarre is *removed* from office, he's no longer governor -- but if Foughbarre is recalled or impeached, he might survive and remain in office.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, See also [What is the difference between a recall and impeachment?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-recall-and-impeachment) and [What is the difference between impeachment and removal?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-impeachment-and-removal)

Comment: @agc, in those jurisdictions that permit it, recall (unlike impeachment, which is analogous to an indictment) effects immediate removal. If recalled, Gov. Foughbarre is removed from office, e.g., CA and Gray Davis. Recall is the name for the mechanism by which _voters_ effect removal. Expulsion is how bodies remove their own members. In the context of the question, remove and recall are equivalent, unless you want to quibble that the OP could also consider assassinating his Senator as a method of removal.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, A famous example:  recall and removal were not equivalent for [Scott Walker in 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisconsin_gubernatorial_recall_election).

Comment: @agc You seem consistently confused by the difference between a recall *election* and its result. Walker faced a recall election. He won. Had he lost, h3 would have been removed from office. See also, impeachment and conviction.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, General usage is somewhat ambiguous, as *recall* can be synonymous with the general process of petition for recall and recall election irrespective of outcome.  Example 2012 usage: *"Wisconsin Gov. Scott Walker Survives Recall : It's All Politics : NPR".

Answer (score 1):

They would have to hope that that representative or senator was impeached, or attempt to place pressure on them to resign. They can not be recalled, as the Constitution does not permit this.

Comment: There's no need to impeach a senator or representative; the Senate and the House can unilaterally expel members without needing to get the other chamber involved.